# Creating JDBC Connection in SOAPUI

Tags: java, mysql, soap, jdbc, soapui

I am new to SOAPUI and have been trying to do query and procedure testing using SOAPUI. 
I went through the SOAPUI documentation on net however I am not able to establish an connection to my DB..
I have copied the mysql jar in the lib folder of SOAPUI. 
The exception I get is

```
Tue Nov 08 12:54:51 IST 2011:ERROR:com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIException: Failed to init connection for drvr [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver], connectionString [jdbc:mysql://DB SERVER IP:PORT/DB NAMES?user=username&password=password]
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong...
Here are the steps of what I did in SOAPUI for this JDBC thing:-

```
> 1.New project.
> 2. Clock on New Project.
> 3.Go to JDBC Connections tab.
> 4. Add a new Data Connection.
> 5. Specified unique name.
> 6. selected driver as mysql:com.jdbc.driver
> 7.I can only see to mention host,port and DB.
> 8.Mentioned Host,Port and DB..
> 9.Tested the Connection.
> 10.Got the above mentioned excpetion...
```

Please help anyone...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try the following. I had the same problem once and the following was working for me:

- Download the JAR for MySQL again. In my case it happened that the JAR itself was corrupt.
- Copy the JAR to %soapUI Folder%\bin\ext

Comment: I think the second point is important. You have to copy the JAR to %soapUI%/bin/ext and not %soapUI%/lib

Comment: Hi this  change worked when using the soapui interface. But when i tried integrating it with maven getting the same error again.

Comment: !Important. After you copy the jar make sure you restart ready api

Answer (score 5):

This worked perfectly fine for me!

1. Download the mySQL connector tar.gz file from here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html
2. Copy it at \SmartBear\SoapUI-Pro-5.0.0\bin\ext path
3. Extract it and Restart the application
4. Test the connection again! :)

Comment: the exact folder path for me on my mac OSX 10.11.6: /Applications/SoapUI-5.2.1.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/ext. I downloaded the .zip file from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

Answer (score 2):

Driver jar must be in ext folder and you also need to register a driver before actually using it.
for example to register postgresql driver use :

```
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver("org.postgresql.Driver")
```

Answer (score 2):

For me coping mysql jar in lib folder worked <%soapUI%/lib> and not <%soapUI%/bin/ext>

Comment: For me, copying the H2 jar to `lib` worked fine. It didn't work in `ext`. Downloaded from [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

Copy the `ojdbc6.jar` in `lib` and `ext` folders.

Answer (score 0):

check your connections strings. It could be different.Are you trying to add using datasource? or script?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to restart once you have downloaded the driver and included it in the directory.